# how to close layer that showed in other layer in cocos2d-iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cclayer, ccscene

I have one layer called alayer, and there is a button called abutton, when click the button, another layer called blayer will show in alayer, not replaceScene, please look at the following code,

alayer.m

```
-(void)abuttonclicked:(id)sender
{
  blayer *blayer = [blayer node];
  blayer.position = ccp(1,1);
  [self addChild:blayer];
}
```

blayer.m has a button called bbutton and string value called bstring, I want to click the b button, it will close blayer (remove blayer from alayer), and pass the string value bstring to alayer, please look at following code,

```
 -(void)bbuttonclicked:(id)sender
 {
  // how can do here to close its self(remove its self from alayer), and pass the bstring to alayer?
 }
```

thanks.

ps. I can use NSUserDefault to pass the string value, but I think it's a bad way to do this, is there another way to pass value?

Answer (score 0):

maybe to pass the string you could declare and implement a property in ALayer.h/.m

```
 @property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *stringFromLayerB;
```

to remove bLayer when bButtonClicked :

```
 -(void)bbuttonclicked:(id)sender
 {
     ALayer *lay = (ALayer*) self.parent;
     lay.stringFromLayerB = @"Whatever you want to set";
     [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
 }
```

There are other ways to do this. You could implement a callback mechanism , use notifications, some kind of delegate protocol binding BLayer and ALayer. All depends what your real (unsaid) requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your scenario, I think its better to use **NSNotificationCenter**.
You can post notification from blayer when the button is tapped and add an observer in alayer to respond exactly how to want.

Add `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedNotification:) name:@"BlayerNotification" object:nil];` in alayer's init and `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` in its dealloc.

Its selector like:

```
- (void)receivedNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSString *string = (NSString *)notification.object;
    NSLog (@"String received %@", string);
}
```

Now you can post notification from blayer when hte button is clicked:

```
-(void)bbuttonclicked:(id)sender {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BlayerNotification" object:self];
    [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}
```